# c# - Async background task with periodic trigger

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, background-process

How can I implement an async background task (to get a httpresponsemessage) that runs each 5 hours?

Comment: Do you mean a timer?

Comment: Yes! This is what I ment

Comment: have you looked at System.Timers.Timer?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest solution would be to create a Class Library (DLL) project that do the magic stuff you like with a HttpClient (or alternative).
When you put this code within a separate assembly, you have the options to either call the code from an Console Application (EXE) and run that from a standard Scheduled Task on a server. Or you can call the same code from a Windows Service (EXE). Both to be executed at the desired sequence or period.

May not be a solution for you, but should be a pointer to a solution based on the details in your question.